# Как монтируемой директории присвоить права на запись?

Tags: debian, permissions, mount

Произвожу монтирование директории:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=name,password=password //192.168.1.1/\!directory$/ /home/www/directory
```

Однако права на запись у нее отсутствуют.

Пробовал так:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=name,password=password,umask=0777 //192.168.1.1/\!directory$/ /home/www/directory
```

но получаю ошибку

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
```

Как примонтировать директорию и установить на нее права на запись?

Answer (score 0):

umask помечается как deprecated, вместо него dir_mode. Все работает.

Comment: `man mount.cifs` зачастую проясняет ситуацию :)